# Generate random numbers from a particular column

Tags: pandas, random

I have a dataset in this form

```
item_id  EAN   Price
3434     232    34
3233     412    28
```

There are totally 54344 datapoints.

I want to random print 40 values from EAN. I tried some techniques like

```
df=pd.read_csv('item_desc.csv')
print(df['EAN'].random.rand(40))
```

but it doesn't worked. Can someone suggest me the code

Answer (score 2):

you can use `sample`:

```
df.sample(n=40)
```